# Two players shooting a target alternately

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

> Two players **A** and **B** shoot a target alternately, until somebody hits it and wins the game. Player **A** takes the first shot. Each time they take a shot, their probabilities of hitting the target are $p$ and $q$ respectively. Which is the probability $\mathbb{P}$ that **A** wins?

**Is the following solution correct ?**

**A** wins if :

he wins with the $1$st shot **or**

they both fail to hit it during the first $2$ shots, and A hits it with the $3$rd shot **or**

they both fail to hit it during the first $4$ shots, and A hits it with the $5$rd shot **or**

...

So,

$$
\mathbb{P} = p + (1-p)(1-q)p + (1-p)^2(1-q)^{2}p + ... = 
p\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(1-p)(1-q)]^n =
\cfrac{p}{p+q-pq}
$$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes it is correct !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability of first player rolling double six first](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587870/probability-of-first-player-rolling-double-six-first)

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate because here $p \neq q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it is correct.

Alternatively, you can condition on the first outcome. If $A$ doesn't win in the first outcome, the first two trials must be failure and then it is a renewal process.

$$\mathbb{P}=p + (1-p)(1-q)\mathbb{P}$$
$$(1-(1-p)(1-q))\mathbb{P}=p$$
$$\mathbb{P}=\frac{p}{1-(1-p)(1-q)}$$